# magento 2 how to create a store and store view in customer_save_after_data_object observer?

Tags: magento2, customer, event-observer

create the observer sucessfully the add the create store code but there is an error    "Something went wrong while saving the customer." 
[image]

the code is given below-

```
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Observer;
 use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
 use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\GroupFactory;
use Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Group;
use Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Store;
use Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Website;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreFactory;
use Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteFactory;


 class CustomerSaveAfterEvent implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_request;
    protected $_layout;
    protected $_objectManager = null;
    protected $_customerGroup;
    private $logger;
    protected $_customerRepositoryInterface;


    private $websiteFactory;
    private $websiteResourceModel;
    private $storeFactory;
    private $groupFactory;
    private $groupResourceModel;
    private $storeResourceModel;
    private $eventManager;

    private $_customerFactory;


public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,

    WebsiteFactory $websiteFactory,
    Website $websiteResourceModel,
    Store $storeResourceModel,
    Group $groupResourceModel,
    StoreFactory $storeFactory,
    GroupFactory $groupFactory,
    ManagerInterface $eventManager
){
    $this->_layout = $context->getLayout();
    $this->_request = $context->getRequest();
    $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
    $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;

    $this->websiteFactory = $websiteFactory;
    $this->websiteResourceModel = $websiteResourceModel;
    $this->storeFactory = $storeFactory;
    $this->groupFactory = $groupFactory;
    $this->groupResourceModel = $groupResourceModel;
    $this->storeResourceModel = $storeResourceModel;
    $this->eventManager = $eventManager;
}

public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
{   
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $customer = $observer->getCustomerDataObject();
    $customerId = $customer->getId();
    $customer->getFirstName();  
    $customerData = $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);
    $is_admin_approved = $customerData->getCustomAttribute('is_admin_approved')->getValue();

    if($is_admin_approved == 1){

        $customer_data = $this->_customerFactory->create()->getCollection()
                        ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('eq' => $customerId))
                        ->getData();    
        $customer_group_id = $customer_data[0]['group_id'];

        if($customer_group_id == 4){

            $seller_store_code = 'seller_store_'.$customerId;
            $seller_store_name = 'Seller Store '.$customerId;

            $website = $this->websiteFactory->create();
            $website->load('base');

            if($website->getId()){
                $group = $this->groupFactory->create();
                $group->setWebsiteId($website->getWebsiteId());
                $group->setName($seller_store_name);
                $group->setRootCategoryId(2);
                $group->setDefaultStoreId(3);
                $this->groupResourceModel->save($group);
            }

            $store = $this->storeFactory->create();

            $store->load('my_custom_store_code');
            if(!$store->getId()){
                $group = $this->groupFactory->create();
                $group->load('Seller', 'name');
                $store->setCode($seller_store_code);
                $store->setName($seller_store_name);
                $store->setWebsite($website);
                $store->setGroupId($group->getId());
                $store->setData('is_active','1');
                $this->storeResourceModel->save($store);
                $this->eventManager->dispatch('store_add', ['store' => $store]);
            } 
        }
    }

   }
 }
```

Comment: can you share which event you are using?

Comment: customer_save_after_data_object

Answer (score 1):

change event from

```
customer_save_after_data_object
```

In this event data not save yet. you can't update data in this event.

to

```
customer_save_commit_after
```